# Column name not found

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran new query to overwrite a set of existing tables. The table schema changed as one of the expected results. So, as of the schema, one new column was added and two others were deleted. Suppose the one column added is named A

After a couple of minutes, when I query :

```
select A
from 'table_*'
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170831'
```

I had error: `Name A not found`

But this query just worked:

```
select A
from 'table_20170831'
```

Just wondering why. Because I really need to query for a longer period of time by using _TABLE_SUFFIX.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just wondering why

The reason why you are getting this error is because the schema is being identified by earliest available sharded table - so in your case it means that in earliest table (table_*) there is/was no field named A

To workaround this - I would recommend creating dummy table with lowest date and with schema that consists all fields that you plan to query

Comment: so you are saying table_*  with suffix 20170831 is different from table_20170831?   I don't think I really understand this...

Comment: I did the same thing to this table earlier today by just adding one column. everything worked fine. Until, this time, I removed another two columns at the same time....

Comment: what I am saying is - when you use `table_*` bigquery engine scans all table with that prefix and identifies scheme based on earliest one

Comment: do you still have questions on this?

Comment: gotcha a little bit....  how long will the deprecated schema stay then?

Comment: as long as "earliest" table with old schema is present in your dataset

Comment: as I said, the old table is overwritten. So from my perspective, that "earliest" table, with the "earliest" schema, should not be there anymore

Comment: As per your suggestion, do you mean  "select wanted-columns from table_20170831"  and save result to another table prefix?

Comment: Good question - yes - with small correction  - `select wanted-columns from table_20170831 where false` so you create empty table with needed schema

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean by "earliest". Yes, there are other days that are still with the old schema. BigQuery would check schema across all tables with the same prefix before apply _TABLE_SUFFIX condition

Comment: exactly, sorry if my wording was not that clear :) - consider voting up the answer if it was helpful

Comment: "select wanted-columns from table_20170831 where false so you create empty table with needed schema" ha... nice tip to learn.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `*` matches a table that doesn't contain the newly added columns, and the schema of the wildcard table comes from the "latest" table based on its creation time. For example, you may have:

- table_20170831: contains two new columns
- table_foo: does not contain two new columns

In this case the `*` will match the second table. To fix this, use a longer prefix, such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_2017*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '0831';
```

For more reading, refer to the documentation on [the schema used for evaluation of wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#schema_used_for_query_evaluation).