# Biqquery - A Metric Shared in All Table Schemas is Not Being Recognized when using BQ Wild Card Function to loop through those Tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to perform a BQ Wild Card Function on a BQ table that is named a certain way. Let's call it `ProjectId.DatasetId.p_Table_##########`. The remaining suffix of `.p_Table_` represents UNIQUETABLEID. I'm using the wild card function to pull the same data from each individual table with the `.p_Table_`.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
_TABLE_SUFFIX as UNIQUETABLEID,
...
total.A,
total.B
FROM `ProjectId.DatasetId.p_Table_*` as total
```

NOTE that Variables A & B  are both STRINGS

All the individual `.p_Table_` tables have the same schema and the wild card function was working just fine last week. However, for some reason, the query is not recognizing two variables **A** and **B** in those tables even those they are in the `.p_Table_` schemas still. It keeps popping up with this error:

```
Error: A not found inside total at [5:20]
```

Same Type of error comes up for **B**

I tested pulling the same metrics for individual tables of `ProjectId.DatasetId.p_Table_##########` and it recognized all the variables just fine.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Could someone please explain why the BQ Wild Card Function call will not recognize **A** and **B** when looking through all suffixes of table `.p_Table_` even though those metrics appear in the schema still?
2. OR, does someone have a better solution to loop through all these BQ tables to gather those metrics WITHOUT the Brute Force approach of pulling from ALL the individual tables and using UNION ALL? (There are 35 tables associated with this `.p_Table_` and it'll be expected to grow, so we want this to be automated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column name not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061964/column-name-not-found)

Comment: The link was understandable, but my situation did not involve overwriting a set of existing tables with `.p_Table_` prefix to manipulate their columns. I am simply pulling certain columns from existing table schemas. I never changed their columns and `.p_Table_` has no other suffixes (such as "foo") besides the UNIQUEIDS ones I expect. So, they all are in the form `.p_Table_########` . In fact, I have not added any new `.p_Table_` tables (its been the same 35 tables). Based on my analysis and reviewing each of the tables, there really should be no issue of it recognizing ""earliest" schema.

Comment: I will certainly keep trying to create a dummy table with such "lowest date" schema, but I don't think it'll completely work based on what I shared with you above.